# How to open file in vim while having session autoload?

Tags: file, session, vim, text-editor

I have following code in .vimrc to automatically save / load session on vim start:

```
" Session saving
" Automatically save / rewrite the session when leaving Vim
augroup leave
        autocmd VimLeave * mksession! ~/.vim/session.vim
augroup END

" Automatically silently load the session when entering vim
autocmd VimEnter * silent source ~/.vim/session.vim
```

Which works properly, the only issue I have is when I want to create new file or open existing with:

```
vim test.txt
```

In this case file is not opened and instead I have the last saved session loaded.

The desired behavior is following. When I run `vim` with no arguments - it restores last session. If I provide file argument, e.x. `vim test.py` - it loads last session AND in new tab opens / creates provided file.
How to do it? Ideally without any plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
" use ++nested to allow automatic file type detection and such
autocmd VimEnter * ++nested call <SID>load_session()

function! s:load_session()
    " save curdir and arglist for later
    let l:cwd = getcwd()
    let l:args = argv()
    " source session
    silent source ~/.vim/session.vim
    "restore curdir (otherwise relative paths may change)
    call chdir(l:cwd)
    " open all args
    for l:file in l:args
        execute 'tabnew' l:file
    endfor
    " add args to our arglist just in case
    execute 'argadd' join(l:args)
endfunction
```

Comment: I copied this, but getting:
`Error detected, while processing VimEnter * Auto commands for "*"
E492: not an editor command: ++nested call <SID>load_session()` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I changed `++nested` to `nested` and got error: unknown function `chdir`. I commented line with `call chdir(l:cwd)` and it seems to work as I wanted. Is that ok or there might be some unexpected things?

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` You're running an outdated version of vim. You can use `execute 'cd' fnameescape(l:cwd)` instead. Though 'tis better to upgrade to the actual version.