# How to make sure proper statusline highlighting is loaded from .vimrc in Vim

Tags: vim, statusbar, color-scheme

I'm making custom statusline for VIM. I want the color of the statusline change dynamically, based on current mode. I achieve this via:

```
" Automatically change the statusline color depending on mode

hi NormalColor guifg=Black guibg=Green ctermbg=46 ctermfg=0
hi InsertColor guifg=Black guibg=Cyan ctermbg=51 ctermfg=0
hi ReplaceColor guifg=Black guibg=maroon1 ctermbg=165 ctermfg=0
hi VisualColor guifg=Black guibg=Orange ctermbg=202 ctermfg=0


set laststatus=2
set statusline=
set statusline+=%#NormalColor#%{(mode()=='n')?'\ \ NORMAL\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#InsertColor#%{(mode()=='i')?'\ \ INSERT\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#ReplaceColor#%{(mode()=='R')?'\ \ RPLACE\ ':''}
set statusline+=%#VisualColor#%{(mode()=='v')?'\ \ VISUAL\ ':''}
```

And it works perfect when I execute `:source .vimrc` Howewer it doesn't work automatically on Vim start.  I put the highlighting after setting colorscheme and dark mode, but still I have this issue.

I believe it has something to do with session loading I have in .vimrc One can refer [How to open file in vim while having session autoload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56324295/how-to-open-file-in-vim-while-having-session-autoload)

```
silent source ~/.vim/session.vim
```

Also there are no issues if I use custom colors like `DiffAdd` or colorscheme ones like `GruvboxPurple`

I found workaround via grouping:

```
augroup coloring
    autocmd VimEnter * hi NormalColor guifg=Black guibg=Green ctermbg=46    ctermfg=0
    autocmd VimEnter * hi InsertColor guifg=Black guibg=Cyan ctermbg=51 ctermfg=0
    autocmd VimEnter * hi ReplaceColor guifg=Black guibg=maroon1 ctermbg=165 ctermfg=0
    autocmd VimEnter * hi VisualColor guifg=Black guibg=Orange ctermbg=202 ctermfg=0
augroup END
```

But I feel that I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What are `set laststatus? statusline?` on startup? Try `set ssop-=options | mksession` in case you're overwriting the options in Session.vim.

Comment: Does not work means that statusline colors are not used. 
`set laststatus? statusline?` shows the statusline string as it should be.
`set ssop-=options | mksession!` turns on correct highlighting for statusline, but breaks syntax highlighting for the whole file

Comment: `breaks syntax highlighting` You can't break "syntax". Most probably, it's the file type info missing. Make sure you have "++nested" while loading session.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm having issues with upgrading to 8.1, so I don't use ++nested option

Comment: You can use "nested" (w/o plus-plus) then.

Comment: Changed to `nested`, but still no effect

Comment: Remove your session file and put `set ssop-=options` into vimrc.

Comment: It worked, thank you. Please, post your comment as answer, so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're saving the options in Session.vim (`set ssop+=options` --- this is Vim's default!), which is loaded *after* vimrc, therefore, upon the startup the options saved in Session.vim *do redefine* the options from vimrc. You can either always keep them synchronized (which is inconvenient, IMO), or (better) *not to save* them in Session file.

However, if you don't have any options saved in Session.vim then you also lose filetype info for all opened buffers.

Normally, filetype info is set with the help of autocommand mechanism. However, by default Vim forbids recursive autocommand invocation (i.e. invocating an autocommand while executing another autocommand). So if you load the Session file *by an autocommand* then filetype detection is effectively prohibited.

So basically you have the following choices:

- disable `options` (not to interfere with global settings in vimrc) but add `localoptions` (so additional buffer settings are saved)
- disable `options` and use `++nested` (or `nested` for old Vim version) to explicitly allow recursive autocommands
- disable `options` and do not use autocommands to load session (e.g. use `vim -S`)

IMO, (1) feels a bit awkward, as some options set in vimrc could be global-local, so some conflicts may potentially arise.